# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I custom notification in application by use windowmanager to addview.

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@74b2eff is not valid; is your activity running?
>        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:685)
>       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:319)
>        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>       at com.zuck3.petpolar.manager.InboxNotificationManager.showInboxNotification(InboxNotificationManager.java:82)
>      at com.zuck3.petpolar.activity.Inbox.InboxActivity.onCreate(InboxActivity.java:66)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6376)
>        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>    W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>    W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>   W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1

InboxNotificationManager.java

```
public class InboxNotificationManager {
private static InboxNotificationManager instance;
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams;
private InboxNotificationView notificationView;
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private Animation.AnimationListener animationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        hideInboxNotification();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
};


public static InboxNotificationManager Instance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new InboxNotificationManager(context);
    }
    return instance;

}

public InboxNotificationManager(Context context) {
    notificationView = new InboxNotificationView(context);
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
    mWindowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mWindowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    mWindowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
    mWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notificationView.stopAnimation(animationListener);

        }
    };


}

public void setTextMeesage(String meesage) {
    notificationView.setTextMessage(meesage);
    //  Toast.makeText(InboxNotificationManager.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

public void showInboxNotification(String message) {
    if (notificationView.getWindowToken() == null) {
        mWindowManager.addView(notificationView, mWindowParams);
        notificationView.startAnimation();
        setTextMeesage(message);

    } else {
        // mWindowManager.setText(count);

    }
    notificationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notificationView.stopAnimation(animationListener);

        }
    });

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);


}

public void hideInboxNotification() {
    if (notificationView.getWindowToken() != null) {
        mWindowManager.removeView(notificationView);
    }


}
```

And when I use this class

```
InboxNotificationManager.Instance(BaseActivity.this).showInboxNotification("Hello world");
```

Thankyou and sorry my bad english.

Comment: Did you check out other answers associated with this error here on SO? I found 2-3. Share your whole `onCreate` method please.

Comment: If your activity is finishing and at that time the view is added, it will throw this exception. So before showing a view/dialog, check `if(!isFinishing())` in activity.

Comment: Thank for answer . But I want show my custom view every activity that I want likeToast.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity is running, use

```
if(mActivity != null && !mActivity.isFinishing())
```

to check